# CRM Analytics - Unable to find error log download in Jobs Monitor

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I am trying to load data to CRM Analytics via external data upload using Middleware tools.

I got an email saying 10k records failed and 90k records succeeded.

Below is the email content

> *"Download the error log from the data monitor to view the failed rows and the reasons they failed."*

However when i goto Job Monitor and open the related job , i do not find any option to download error logs.

Please advise if you have come across similar situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue this morning. I was able to click the "Manage Dataflows" link listed at the bottom of the Data Manager left hand navigation menu (see first screen snip) which opened a new Monitor page. I then expanded the job with failures to show node details and clicked the download link listed after the Warning status to obtain the error file (see second screen snip).

Best,
Ginny

[image: Data Manager]

[image: Monitor]

Comment: Thank you so much